# Symfony2 - Nested Firewalls

Tags: symfony

is there way to configure nested firewalls ? Here is what I want to do:

User enter site, site ask him for his age. This is 1st firwall. If he enter above 18 years, he get authenticated with 1st firewall and redirected to second firewall's login else he get error page.

In second firewall he must enter code. If code is correct he get authenticated with second firewall else he can enter code again (he must NOT authenticated again with 1st firewall).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get the behavior you need with roles.  For example, `ROLE_LT_18` and `ROLE_ADULT`.  Then for access control, something like:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/youth, role: ROLE_LT_18 }
    - { path: ^/adult, role: ROLE_ADULT }
```

And in controllers, something like this:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

    /**
     * 
     * @Route("/adult")
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADULT')")
     */
    class AdminController extends Controller
    {
    ...
    }
```

and

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

/**
 * 
 * @Route("/youth")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_LT_18')")
 */
class YouthController extends Controller
{
...
}
```